# Write large JSON in chunks as Flux<ByteBuffer> using Jackson to AWS S3

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, jackson, project-reactor, jackson-databind

I have a large Java object in memory I'd like to serialize to JSON using Jackson and upload to AWS S3 of about 2GB, without keeping the whole JSON in memory.

The easiest way to achieve this is like so:

```
byte[] data = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
...
s3AsyncClient.putObject(request, AsyncRequestBody.fromBytesUnsafe(data));
```

This creates a `byte[]` in memory of about 2GB (and another copy of 2GB when using the non-unsafe `AsyncRequestBody.fromBytes(data)`).

I'd like to avoid this by streaming the data in smaller chunks, directly from Jackson to AWS. AWS S3 exposes an `AsyncRequestBody.fromPublisher(Publisher<ByteBuffer>)` which lets you stream data incrementally.

**How can I get a `Flux<ByteBuffer>` from Jackson when serializing an object without having to write the complete JSON to memory first?**

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use the `writeValue` from the `ObjectMapper` that takes an `OutputStream` and let the copy to the `ByteBuffer`. Using `writeValueAsBytes` or `writeValueAsString` will not work as that will be to in-memory only.

Comment: Any chance you could work that out into an example and answer, @M.Deinum? Particularly interested to see how to connect the `OutputStream` to the Reactor paradigm and making sure it gets closed & cleaned up correctly.

Comment: There are several implementation on the internet on an `OutputStream` that writes to a `ByteBuffer` (even some products like Avro) provide an out of the box implementation. You can use those for inspiration I suspect. They all more or less do the same, wrap a `ByteBuffer` and when write is called onto the `OutputStream` directly write into the `ByteBuffer`. You could wrap all that into a `Publisher` (a `Mono` I would imagine) which would call `object.mapper.write` with the sspecial `OutputStream`.